# Selecting ReactJS a component dynamically, as a default of sorts

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs

Is it possible to some how trigger a component through reactjs that isn't some sort of hackish behavior? Example I have a large set of objects that share similar groupings. From which I generate a menu of sorts or tabs based on each group. From which the user can select from and see the sub objects for that grouping.

Thing is, you see a UI thats essentially half empty when you land on it initially. So what I'd like to do is somehow select the First component in the groups navigation and have that call out its sub group for display.

I know if I was using jQuery I could simply do

```
$('.group-tab:first').click();
```

But I am trying to create this method in React without jQuery and without one-off methods if at all possile

Comment: I suggest you control which group is showing in the state of your top-level component.  Then rather than firing a click event to open a group, you can use `setState` to switch the active group.

Comment: Oh, no I don't want to fire a click off. Just simply implying the notion of what one might do with jQuery as I am more familiar with jQuery than I am with React at the moment.

Comment: I posted an example below.  Let me know if it helps clarify my previous comment.

Comment: It definitely does, thank you. All though for a Friday, this is more thinking than I have to offer at the moment, only because I've already devised most of the apps needs I am working on currently (its down to the visual astetics at this point), and have to figure out where/how to add something like this into my logic

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you control which group is showing in the state of your top-level component.  Here is a minimal working example in [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mark1z/srmhgroo/1/), with the code below, in which you can switch groups by clicking on the `<li>` items.  You can use a call to the function `changeGroup` from anywhere within the `App` component to change the active group.  In this example the function callback is passed to the `onClick` event handlers for the `<li>` elements.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        this.state={active_group: 0};
        this.changeGroup = this.changeGroup.bind(this);
    }
    changeGroup(group_id){
        this.setState({active_group: group_id});
    }
    render() {
        //this is a rough implementation
        var group = '';
        if (this.state.active_group == 1){
            group = <Group1/>;
        }
        else if (this.state.active_group == 2){
            group = <Group2/>;
        }
        else if (this.state.active_group == 3){
            group = <Group3/>;
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <ul> 
                    Here is the nav 
                    <li onClick={this.changeGroup.bind(this,1)}> Group 1 </li>
                    <li onClick={this.changeGroup.bind(this,2)}> Group 2 </li>
                    <li onClick={this.changeGroup.bind(this,3)}> Group 3 </li>
                </ul>
                {group}
            </div>
        );
    }
};

 class Group1 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(<div> Group 1 now showing </div>)
    }
};

class Group2 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(<div> Group 2 now showing </div>)
    }
};

class Group3 extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(<div> Group 3 now showing </div>)
    }
};



React.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```